# Get value from line and remove leading 0s and add to string

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to convert a .dat to a .csv. What I need help with is removing the leading zeros from the current line and make the number a variable and then add it to a string. Heres the .dat file:

```
0004|IP
0006|IP
0008|IP
```

it currently writes to the file:

```
('0004\\Registers,Register  21',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  21',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0004\\Registers,Register  22',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  22',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0004\\Registers,Register  23',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  23',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0004\\Registers,Register  24',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  24',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0004\\Registers,Register  25',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  25',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0004\\Registers,Register  26',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  26',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0006\\Registers,Register  21',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  21',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0006\\Registers,Register  22',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  22',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0006\\Registers,Register  23',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  23',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0006\\Registers,Register  24',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  24',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0006\\Registers,Register  25',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  25',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0006\\Registers,Register  26',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  26',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0008\\Registers,Register  21',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  21',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0008\\Registers,Register  22',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  22',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0008\\Registers,Register  23',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  23',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0008\\Registers,Register  24',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  24',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0008\\Registers,Register  25',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  25',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')

('0008\\Registers,Register  26',  ',IP',  'Store    -  Register  26',  '',  'LAN  (TCP)',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '',  '0x1')
```

I need 'store' to be followed by the number without the zeros, one more thing, can you also help me to remove the parenthesis and the quotations from the output? Thanks!

```
import os
import csv

exists = os.path.isfile('stores.dat')
if exists:
    print('creating phone book')
    with open('stores.dat', 'r') as input_file:
        lines = input_file.readlines()
        newLines = []
        for line in lines:
            registers2 = 21
            while registers2 < 27:
                newLine = line[:4] + '\Registers,' + 'Register ' + str(registers2), ',IP','Store ' + '' + ' - Register ' + str(registers2), '', "LAN (TCP)", '', '', '', '','','', '', '', '0x1'
                newLines.append([newLine])
                registers2 = registers2 + 1
    with open('file.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
        file_writer.writerows(newLines)
```

This is what I need it to look like:

```
0004\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 4 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x1
0004\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 4 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x1
0004\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 4 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x1
0004\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 4 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x1
0004\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 4 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x1
0004\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 4 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.writer.writerows` takes a list of lists.  Don't try to add the commas to the line yourself.  That's what the csv module is for.

Instead read your file one line at a time and write each line separately.  You can use the `csv` module for both reading and writing:

```
import os
import csv

exists = os.path.isfile('stores.dat')
if exists:
    print('creating phone book')

    # When using csv, open files with newline=''
    with open('stores.dat','r',newline='') as input_file:
        with open('file.csv','w',newline='') as output_file:
            reader = csv.reader(input_file,delimiter='|')
            writer = csv.writer(output_file)
            for line in reader:
                for registers2 in range(21,27):
                    # Python 3.6+ f-strings for easier formatting.
                    # Make a list of columns.
                    newLine = [f'{line[0]}\Registers',f'Register {registers2}',line[1],f'Store {int(line[0])} - Register {registers2}','','LAN (TCP)','','','','','','','','','0x01']
                    writer.writerow(newLine)
```

Output:

```
0004\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 4 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 4 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 4 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 4 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 4 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0004\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 4 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 6 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 6 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 6 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 6 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 6 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0006\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 6 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 21,IP,Store 8 - Register 21,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 22,IP,Store 8 - Register 22,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 23,IP,Store 8 - Register 23,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 24,IP,Store 8 - Register 24,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 25,IP,Store 8 - Register 25,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
0008\Registers,Register 26,IP,Store 8 - Register 26,,LAN (TCP),,,,,,,,,0x01
```

Comment: would you possibly know how to add 8 registers for 0008 and keep the rest a 6 registers?